# Is there a way in SQL Server to insert into TempTable parallely?

Tags: c#, sql

I have a Dynamic SQl Query as below

```
Create #TempTable(ColumnA int, ColumnB int, ColumnC Int)

Insert into #TempTable(select A,B,C from Table1 where  some condition formed dynamically)
Insert into #TempTable(select A,B,C from Table1 where  some condition formed dynamically)
Insert into #TempTable(select A,B,C from Table1 where  some condition formed dynamically)
Insert into #TempTable(select A,B,C from Table1 where  some condition formed dynamically)
Insert into #TempTable(select A,B,C from Table1 where  some condition formed dynamically)

select * from #TempTable
drop table #TempTable
```

Note : The Number of insert statements into the #TempTablecan vary from 10 to 100 hence it takes a lot of time to execute

What i wanted to know is , Is There a way in SQL server 2008 R2 using which i can execute the Insert statements parallely and Reduce the Execution Time??

Comment: Where is your execution time spent? CPU calculation or IO?

Comment: Who is creating each "condition formed dynamically"? Your SQL code, or an external program?

Comment: Instead of selecting into #TempTable to only select from it and drop it, then try to just union your queries together. It seems like a lot of redundant work to do it in that manner. Also depending on your actual "dynamic logic" there might be better ways to solve this entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Create a varchar variable to hold your insert statements. Add a While loop and append  the insert statements to the varchar variable. You can then execute the sql like this: sp_executesql @sql

Answer (score 0):

Alternative of Temporary table is the Table variable which can do all kinds of operations that we can perform in Temp table. Below is the syntax for using Table variable

```
Declare @TempTable TABLE(
ColumnA int, ColumnB int, ColumnC Int)

Insert into @TempTable
select 1 as ColumnA,2 as ColumnB,3  as ColumnC
```

Tablevariable is always useful for less data.